# spring failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.reflect.Type'

Tags: java, spring

I am using a library that has this bean defied:

```
<bean id="campaignCpcCacheClientFactory" class="com.mycompany.infra.cache.folsom.MemcachedClientFactory" factory-method="createClientFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg name="clientType" value="JSON"/>
    <constructor-arg name="cacheName" value="CampaignCpcCache"/>
    <constructor-arg name="keyTranslator">
      <bean class="com.mycompany.cpc.cachekey.CpcFeaturesCacheKeyTranslator">
        <constructor-arg value="CampaignCPC"/>
      </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="valueType" value="com.mycompany.cpc.CampaignCpc"/>
    <constructor-arg name="expirationSeconds" value="${com.mycompany.cpcfeatures.memcache.ttl_seconds}"/>
    <property name="consulClusterName" value="${com.mycompany.cpcfeatures.memcache.cluster.name}"/>
    <property name="targetsRefreshPeriod" value="10000"/>
  </bean>
```

when I inject this bean as a constructor arg to my own object (on xml)
this crushes on startup, saying:

Failed to create that bean. could not convert factory method argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.reflect.Type].Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [java.lang.reflect.Type]
no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Arg#3 is com.mycompany.cpc.CampaignCpc which is a class on the same dependency module.

Other modules at the same project use that bean and don't have any trouble loading.

Answer (score 0):

I should have created org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean
and generated a String to Type converter class